# Raspberry Pi 4: same VLC-video on two screens

Tags: pi-4, video

I'm trying to convince my Rasp Pi 4B (latest Raspbian OS 32Bit) to display the same video on both monitors.
I've tried the screen config via drag 'n' drop, xrandr and many other things I found on websearches.

Both monitors are from same manufacturer, identically in inches, pixels, framerate, hdmi-connection, etc.

Any solutions?

Comment: what happens when you try?

Comment: Xrandr only produces two different desktops - one with the video, one with desktop icons. Using the screen config I drag 'n' drop the second screen on the first and apply. After restart I have two different screen and not one in both monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching two instances of VLC? If I recall correctly, it is possible to modify VLC settings (on Windows at least) to launch a new process/windows every time you start VLC instead of playing the new file in the same instance.

Comment: That's new to me. I'll try